# How to add "send to deliver-ability seed list" option while sending email in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am trying to send guidedsend mail, while I am sending mails the option called "send to deliverability seed list" is missing as shown in the image.How can i add that option to include seed list

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not pretty sure, but this is an option of Inbox Tools package. If you don't have that package the option it's not useful at all. The documentation states:

> 7.- If you have the Inbox Tools package, you see Seed Lists. Select Send to Deliverability Seed List to run Inbox Detective on your
>   user-initiated send. You can send to a seed list with every
>   user-initiated send or choose the interval you want to send to a seed
>   list.

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/email_messages/how_to_create_a_user_initiated_email_interaction/